# Setting ggplot2 bar plot parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to set specific bar plot parameters for a `ggplot2` bar plot object.

Specifically, I want the bars to start where the y axis value is 1 and, and I want the lower limit to be -1 and the upper limit to be 1.25x the value of the largest graph.

Is this possible? If so, how can this be done?

Some example code is below.

Thanks ahead of time.

---

---

```
# loads ggplot2 package
library(ggplot2)

# displays information about data
colnames(mtcars)
mtcars

# creates bar plot
bar_plot__x_is_cyl__y_is_carb <- 
  # ---- NOTE: sets up ggplot data
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=carb)) + 
  # ---- NOTE: creates bar graph
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), width = .3)
# ---- NOTE: displays bar plot
bar_plot__x_is_cyl__y_is_carb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this? `geom_bar`/`geom_col` always starts from a zero baseline (*except log scales, see help at `?geom_bar`), so if you want the bars to start elsewhere you might want to use `geom_rect` or `geom_tile`. I think `geom_tile` more convenient here, but its `y` is based on the middle point of the bar, so it takes a little algebra to describe:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(y = (carb +1)/2, 
                  height = (carb-1), 
                  width = 0.3)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = -1:10) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 1.25*max(mtcars$carb)))
```

[image]